# How can I get unsigned magnitude of the negative number in python

Tags: python

I have this numbers  `a = 7 , b= 9`

Now I want to subtract the two numbers.

`b - a = 2`. Now that is ok

but `a -b = -2`

But I only want to know the diff i.e 2 not negative or positive like we have mod operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
In [57]: abs(2 - -9)
Out[57]: 11

In [58]: abs(-1 - 5)
Out[58]: 6
```

keeping only 1 solution as suggested by Zero Piraeus

Comment: Providing different solutions depending on the signs of a and b is unnecessary and confusing. `abs(abs(a)-abs(b))` does more work than `àbs(a - b)`, is harder to read, and is wrong half the time, whereas `àbs(a - b)` is always correct.

Answer (score 5):

You want `abs(a - b)`, not `abs(abs(a)-abs(b))`